# Finding the index inside a vector satisfying a condition

Tags: r

I am looking for a condition which will return the index of a vector satisfying a condition.

For example-
I have a vector `b = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.7, 0.9)`
I want to know the first index of b for which say b >0.65. In this case the answer should be 3

I tried `which.min(subset(b, b > 0.65))`
But this gives me 1 instead of 3.

Please help

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use `which` and take the first element of the result:

```
which(b > 0.65)[1]
#[1] 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Be careful, `which.max` is wrong if the condition is never met, it does not return `NA`:

```
> a <- c(1, 2, 3, 2, 5)
> a >= 6
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> which(a >= 6)[1]
[1] NA  # desirable
> which.max(a >= 6)
[1] 1   # not desirable
```

Why? When all elements are equal, `which.max` returns 1:

```
> b <- c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
> which.max(b)
[1] 1
```

Note: FALSE < TRUE

Answer (score 0):

You may use `which.max`:

```
which.max(b > 0.65)
# [1] 3
```

From `?which.max`: "For a logical vector x, [...] `which.max(x)` return[s] the index of the first [...] `TRUE`

```
b > 0.65
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

You should also have a look at the result of your code `subset(b, b > 0.65)` to see why it can't give you the desired result.

Comment: I just downvoted since I found the same error as Phuoc found below. It will return 1 in case the condition never met while Roland 's solution could return NA.