# Making every other vowel in a vector uppercase

Tags: r, string, uppercase

Given a lower case string. Ex:

```
s <- 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

The goal is to make every other vowel in the string an uppercase.

Desired output here:

```
abcdEfghijklmnOpqrstuvwxyz
```

As you can see, since all vowels where used in order, `e` and `o` where uppercase.

There are only lowercase characters in the strings in all cases.

For `aieou`, the desired output is:

```
aIeOu
```

How could I do this in R?

I tried:

```
s[unlist(strsplit(s, '')) %in% c('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')] <- toupper(s[unlist(strsplit(s, '')) %in% c('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')])
```

But no avail.

<sup>Even if this worked, it wouldn't be every other vowel</sup>

R version 4.1.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a one-liner, but:

```
s <- 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

as_list <- unlist(strsplit(s, ''))
vowels <- as_list %in% c('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
every_other_index <- which(vowels)[c(FALSE, TRUE)]

as_list[every_other_index] <- toupper(as_list[every_other_index])

print(paste(as_list, collapse=''))
```

gives:

```
[1] "abcdEfghijklmnOpqrstuvwxyz"
```

(Use of `which` taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22660149/finding-the-index-inside-a-vector-satisfying-a-condition/22660206); use of `c(FALSE, TRUE)]` [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461829/select-every-other-element-from-a-vector).)

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution, using `stringr` and `purrr::map2`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

s <- 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

s %>% 
  str_split("") %>% unlist %>% 
  map2({1:nchar(s) %in% (str_which(.,"[aeiou]") %>% .[c(F,T)])},
       ~ if_else(.y, str_to_upper(.x),.x)) %>% 
  str_c(collapse = "")

#> [1] "abcdEfghijklmnOpqrstuvwxyz"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `gregexpr`, then `gsub`, with `\\U`ppercase pattern replacement.

```
f <- function(s, u=c('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')) {
  v <- sort(unlist(sapply(u, \(u) all(unlist(gregexpr(u, s)) > -1))))
  v <- v[seq_along(v) %% 2 == 0]
  gsub(sprintf('(%s)', paste(names(v[v]), collapse='|')), '\\U\\1', s, perl=TRUE)
}

f('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
# [1] "abcdEfghijklmnOpqrstuvwxyz"

f('world hello')
# [1] "world hEllo"

f('hello world')
# [1] "hEllo world"
```